# Multiple link local default gateway IPv6 addresses once IPv6 enabled

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We have a Windows Server 2012 r2 host. Whenever I enable IPv6 on the host, it gets three IPv6 addresses and 16 IPv6 link local default gateway addresses. Could anyone help me understanding how this could happen? It's working fine with this configuration, by the way.

ipv6 address 1: 2001:4898:e0:f242:203a:b75b:dfe4:28d6
ipv6 address 2: 2001:4898:e0:f242:99f0:411d:2166:74dc
ipv6 address 3: 2001:4898:e0:f243:203a:b75b:dfe4:28d6
another ipv6 link-local address

16 default gateway ipv6 addresses
1 default gateway ipv4 address

Comment: It would help if you provided the actual console output. How many network interfaces do you have? Have you enabled DHCP on the server as well as a router?

Answer (score -1):

You said you get many default gateway addresses, are all these different gateways on the same device, or are they from many different devices?

If you are getting multiple different default gateways from many different devices, then you almost certainly have your Route Advertisement daemons running in a miss-configured way on those various devices you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. They are from the same device. All those ip addresses and gateways belong to one single network interface.